# How to discard local changes and use fresh copy in Access 2013 + SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, ms-access

I am using Access database services in SharePoint 2010 and the database is already published on SharePoint 2010 (Office 365).

I have made some changes in the forms but I don't want to sync it and discard all the local changes and use the fresh copy. I download the database from SharePoint access services site but it is still showing the previous changes. It seems that it saves all the changes made earlier in local computer.

Can you tell me how I can use the fresh copy of the database or discard all the changes and start from latest copy that is already on SharePoint (last time synced)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the downloaded copy is showing previous changes, then previous changes synced. So unless you saved a backup like all developers do before making changes, then I am afraid you are out of luck.

Just keep in mind that you can UN-attach, or save a local un-published copy. I suggest you do this every day, or at least at the start of the day, so if you mess up then like all developers you can import or even cut + paste code from the backup you have.

To save a local "un-attached" or so called un-published database, you simply go file-> save and publish, and choose "save as local database".

However, right now if you are seeing changes in what you download from SharePoint, then that is what was saved and synced to SharePoint. So by downloading a fresh copy, and you see the changes in that fresh copy, then logically this suggests the changes were synced to the server at one point in time.

Also, if this was/is a first time publish, then a un-published AT FIRST publish is created in the same dir as where the Accdb file was. It will be named

```
YouFileName_backup.accDB
```

Comment: Thanks for letting me know that. I thought when I work in Access I am always making changes to local copy except table.